# How to generate avro file using Scala

Tags: scala, avro

I have a used python for doing same. Libraries like fastavro really work. I have the data in csv format and avro schema.

Is the any library in scala that does something like

```
val avro = buildAvro(schema,data)
```

I have really muddled around with this but cannot find a solution

Comment: Give https://github.com/GenslerAppsPod/scalavro a try

Answer (score 1):

Try [avro4s](http://github.com/51zero/avro4s). Once you add it to your build, you can generate a schema as such:

```
val schema = AvroSchema[YourType]
```

Then you can print that out, save it, whatever you need to do with the schema

```
println(schema.toString(true))
```